# Is it possible to use epoll and whether it makes sense to use epoll with Netmap to speedup?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip, epoll

As we known, we can use `poll/select` with Netmap: http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/

Is it possible to use `epoll` and whether it makes sense to use epoll with Netmap, or it has no advantages in speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

netmap author here: we have changes to enable epoll() for linux (the equivalent kevent() on FreeBSD is already supported). The advantage only exists when you have to handle several file descriptors in the same poll/select/epoll/kqueue operation.